# Adding itextsharp dll to project getting error

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I installed iTextsharp from nuget package manager to my project , when I compile and run I get below error:

> Version installed :5.5.5.0
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Comment: Try one of the solutions on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388148/yet-another-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework), specifically removing it and re-adding it. Or better, do you actually need NuGet? Can you just manually download and reference the assembly?

Comment: Could it be that your local security policy is locking downloaded files? Maybe check your itextsharp.dlls file properties if it shows the "unblock" button.

Comment: @ Chris Haas I still get same error. I tried downloading it and adding it manually instead of nuget ..I changed the permission to the folder to full control .. but still no luck

Comment: @Filburt  when i downloaded it manually I was getting that option to Unblock ..i did that and tried I got the same error, than i though let me go via nuget  but still ... same issue .. I am in kind of urgent situation but this  error is giving trouble

Comment: Does your project run without referencing itextsharp? Is your project located on a network share? If this is the case, try running it from a local drive instead.

Comment: @Filburt  My project  is running on my local machine.